# css root element margin

Tags: html, css, margin, w3c

In css **html** element is said to be the **root** element,
and as I'm reading in [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html) its width and height are governed by the browser window/frame.

So, does it make any sense to apply margins to it ?

I think it doesn't because if it is the root element it's not supposed to be contained in a higher level element.

Howewer every browser allows you to add margin to **html** element, any explainations ?

Answer (score 3):

The phrogz.net article is simply wrong. That's really not how it works at all. The html element is a block-level element which can be styled pretty much like any other block level element.

Your page is painted on a [canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/intro.html#the-canvas) of (logically) infinite dimensions which has an origin at point (0, 0). The browser has a [viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#viewport) which shows an area of the canvas. There exists a rectangular block called the [Initial Containing Block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x1) whose top left hand corner is at (0, 0) and has a height and width equal to that of the viewport. The root element's position and dimensions can be specified relative to the Initial Containing Block, just as any other block element's position and dimensions can be specified relative to its [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

---

As an aside, CSS is not just about HTML. It will work with a DOM created in any namespace from any source. In particular it will work with DOMs created from XML. So the root element is not necessarily the `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to add margins to the `<HTML>` element. You should only add margins to the `<body>` and the elements that are in it. Check also http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.3 for the spec

Comment: html is the element highest in the hierachy of html elements, the fact that it also contains head element wich is not shown is not relevant, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties on the `html` element if you like, but that’s not common. It’s normally simpler to set properties on the `body`.

There’s nothing illogical in setting `margin` on `html`. The margin is outside the box of the element and need not appear inside the box of any other element.